# How to create spark dataframe from list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala list `List[Any] = List("a", "b",...)` 
and I need to get a Spark dataframe consisting on an only row with all the columns in the List. I'm trying to create an RDD from this with `sc.parallelize(myList)` which return 
`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] = ParallelCollectionRDD[5834] at parallelize at <console>:81`

but then I can't either select specific elements of this row:
`sc.parallelize(myList).map(line => line(0))`
returns `error: Any does not take parameters`

and I can't either use `toDF()` to obtain my DataFrame

`value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]`

I suppose it has something to do with the type Any, but I need to admit any type, since I don't know what I will be getting in my list

Comment: if you are not sure what you will be getting in the list then converting it to dataframe would be a bad idea as dataframe requires schema with fixed datatypes in columns

Comment: List with one tuple will create one row: List(("a", "b")).toDF

Answer (score 0):

This approach will not work because there is no implicitly provided .toDF function for List[Any].

Even if there was you would be creating a DataFrame with a single column named value with as many rows as there are elements in your original List.

e.g.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toDF
res10: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]
```

You are looking for something like:

```
scala> List(List(1,2,3)).toDF
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<int>]
```